# List of Figures and Tables blank when after Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents

Basically, this is the front matter of my thesis and the list of tables and figures generates just fine when I put it before \tableofcontents but I get a blank page when I put it after. Has anyone here faced this issue before? Code in the pastebin link
https://pastebin.com/6tc1e81W

Comment: what class file you are using?

Comment: Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)  that does not rely on external code hosting services?

Comment: I tried the code from your link and after removing all the `\input{}` of files which I don't have and adding some dummy tables and figures I get entries in the lot and lof, just as expected. Can you please give us some minimal compilable code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for replying. I was looking up how to go about posting a MWE as suggested in the comments but I have solved the issue. Just so if anyone else has the same, I was doing this on Sharelatex and clearing the cache solved the issue. Instructions on the same can be found here.

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Kb/Clearing_the_cache

I hope this helps someone out there! Thank you all for replying so promptly to my issue